# How do I change the identity of a sample from spatial 'Visium' data preprocessing in Seurat v3?

Tags: seurat, single-cell

I'm wanting to create a merged object in Seurat using 2 10x Visium 'slices'. However, when I create an object, Seurat assigns an identity "SeuratProject" to the objects (by default I'm guessing; see attached plot). This will be problematic when I attempt to merge the objects as there will be unintended duplicates of the objects.

Here's what I'm attempting to use to create the 10x Spatial Object:

```
brain1 <- Load10X_Spatial(data.dir = "~/xxx", filename = "filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5", assay = "Spatial", slice = "slice1", filter.matrix = TRUE, to.upper = FALSE)
```

I'd need the ability to assign unique ident to each of these (and any subsequent) slices/data.

Thank you!!

[image: Plot output showing the "SeuratProject" Identity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-assign `orig.ident` after creating the object. For example:

```r
brain1 <-Load10X_Spatial(data.dir = "~/xxx", filename = "filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5", assay = "Spatial", slice = "slice1", filter.matrix = TRUE, to.upper = FALSE)
brain1$orig.ident <- "Visium"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: The active.ident is still "SeuratProject", so also add Idents(brain1) <- "Visium".  There should be a "project" option in Load_10X_Spatial to change the "SeuratProject" default